# Extract names and date using regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have inputs like these:

```
input1 = 'firstName.lastName@email.com - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT Test Task from firstName.lastName@email.com'
input2 = 'firstNamelastName@email.com - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT Test Task from firstNamelastName@email.com'
input3 = 'someName - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT Test Task from someName'
```

And I expect outputs like these:

```
output1 = firstName.lastName@email.com - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT
output2 = firstName@email.com - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT
output3 = someName - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT
```

I want to extract output using regular expressions.

I have tried the following:

```
regularEx = /\w+\.[a-zA-Z]+\s-\s\w{3},\s\d{1,2}\s[a-zA-Z]{3,9}\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s[a-zA-Z]{3}/g

myInput = 'firstName.lastName@email.com - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT Test Task from firstName.lastName@email.com'

regularEx.exec(myInput);
```

Which gives me this output:

```
[
    "com - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT"
]
```

But the expected output is:

```
[
    "firstName.lastName@email.com - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT"
]
```

How can I modify my regular expression to get desired output?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want everything until the date... Dates all end in GMT so you can use this marker.

```
/^.+?GMT/g
```

This will simply take everything plus the first GMT met.

Comment: I think you are correct ! @Saketer

Comment: It works with all your expected inputs OP. So maybe you didn't describe enough?

Comment: I have separate regex for another format - 
    /\w+\s-\s\d{1,2}\/+[a-zA-Z]{3,9}\/\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}/g,

    "admin - 7/May/2015 09:54.51"
    "admin - Thu, 07 May 2015 15:30:01 GMT"

"/^.+?GMT/g" will fail for this format

Answer (score 0):

modify your regular expression as:

```js
const regularEx = /([^\s]+@[^\s]+) - \w{3}, \d{1,2} [A-Za-z]{3,9} \d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [A-Za-z]{3}/g;

const myInput = 'firstName.lastName@email.com - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT Test Task from firstName.lastName@email.com';

const match = regularEx.exec(myInput);
const output = match[1]; // Extracting the captured group

console.log(output); // firstName.lastName@email.com - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

- `([^\s]+@[^\s]+)`: This captures the email address by matching one or
  more non-whitespace characters before and after the @ symbol.
- `\w{3}, \d{1,2} [A-Za-z]{3,9} \d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [A-Za-z]{3}`: This matches the date and time pattern after the email
  address. However, it is not captured as part of the desired output.

By modifying the regular expression as shown above, it will capture the email address and ignore the rest of the string.

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't pass input 3 as there is no email.

Comment: Thanks, @Pushpendra. based on this, I think I can modify my regex for another format as well. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This will do for your examples. I've just made a small change on your regex:

```
"^[\w\.@]+\s-\s\w{3},\s\d{1,2}\s[a-zA-Z]{3,9}\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s[a-zA-Z]{3}"gm
```

Just need to include all the characters that can be used in your user names/emails.

Answer (score 0):

Using a case insensitive pattern with the `/i` flag, you could use:

```
^.*?\s-\s[a-z]{3},\s\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3,9}\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3}\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?\s-\s` Match as few as possible chars and then match a `-` between whitespace chars
- `[a-z]{3},\s\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3,9}\s` The shortened day name, the day and the month
- `\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}` Match a year and time like part
- `\s[a-z]{3}\b` Match 3 chars a-z followed by a word boundary to prevent a partial word match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pm28x7/1)

```js
const regex = /^.*?\s-\s[a-z]{3},\s\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3,9}\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3}\b/i;
[
  'firstName.lastName@email.com - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT Test Task from firstName.lastName@email.com',
  'firstNamelastName@email.com - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT Test Task from firstNamelastName@email.com',
  'someName - Fri, 19 May 2023 10:13:23 GMT Test Task from someName'
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[0]);
  }
})
```

---

**A few alternative options**

If the part before  `-`  can not contain a hyphen, you might also use a negated character class:

```
^[^-]*\s-\s[a-z]{3},\s\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3,9}\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3}\b
```

If there can only be a single name without @ or an email like pattern, you can use an optional non capture group for the @ part:

```
^[^\s@]+(?:@[^\s@]+)?\s-\s[a-z]{3},\s\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3,9}\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ZtguQ/1)